# knockout if-else bind cannot work correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout, currently I met a weird problem. What I want is to use `ko if-else bind`, please see the code below:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   something......
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 Problem comes here...
 <!-- ko ifnot: editing -->
   <td><span data-bind="text: Value" /></td>
   <td><button data-bind="click: Edit">Edit</button></td>
 <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- ko if: editing -->
   <td><input data-bind="value: Value"></td>
   <td><button data-bind="click: Save">Save</button></td>
 <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In ViewModel:

```
 function SettingData(){
  var self = this;
  self.editing = ko.observable(false); 

self.Edit = function () {
    self.editing(true);
};

self.Save = function () {
    self.editing(false);
}
}
```

When start the page, content in if and ifnot statement all come out (it should be wrong). When click "Edit", only content in if statement show up and content in ifnot statement disappear, which is good, but when click "Save", connent in if and ifnot statement all show up.

I don't know which part of my code is incorrect, can anyone give me hand?  Thanks.

Comment: It works here as you want http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5139/

Answer (score 2):

You must add Value observable in the viewmodel. Add below line to function SettingData()

```
self.Value = ko.observable("");
```